# CSSMERR_DL_DATASTORE_DOESNOT_EXIST while trying to import a private key to the keychain

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain, private-key

With my application, I am trying to import a private key into the login keychain.
For this, I create a all the attributes in a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
               forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[attributes setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate
               forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:(2048)]
               forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];
```

Then create a SecKeyRef for the key using

```
SecKeyRef privateKey = SecKeyCreateFromData((CFDictionaryRef)attributes, (CFDataRef)encodedPrivateKeyData, &error);
```

Since I am adding the key to the login keychain, I derive the path to the login keychain and create a SecKeyChainRef for the same using SecKeychainOpen.

```
NSArray *path = [NSHomeDirectory() pathComponents];
//returns /Users/<username>/Library/...
NSString *keychainPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@%@",path[0],path[1],path[2],@"/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"];
SecKeychainRef keychain = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecKeychainOpen([keychainPath UTF8String],&keychain);
```

Once we have the privateKey as well as the keychainRef, we can actually create a representation of the privateKey using

```
CFDataRef exportData = NULL;
status = SecItemExport(privateKey, kSecFormatWrappedPKCS8, 0, &keyParams, &exportData);
```

To finally add the privateKey that was stored in `exportData`, I use

```
CFArrayRef outItems = NULL;
status = SecItemImport(exportData, NULL, &dataFormat, &actualType, 0, &keyParams, keychain, &outItems);
```

The problem occurs with the SecItemImport where I get an OSStatus of
`-25294 errSecNoSuchKeychain - "The specified keychain could not be found"
CSSM Error: Keychain Access CSSM Exception: -2147413737 CSSMERR_DL_DATASTORE_DOESNOT_EXIST` 
The odd thing is that both the SecKeychainOpen and SecItemImport functions use the same SecKeychainRef of the login keychain, but the application can successfully find the keychain only during the SecKeychainOpen function. It fails only during the SecItemImport operation. Since it is the login keychain that has a lot of passwords saved, I'd like to figure out a solution without having to reset the keychain if possible.

This is an isolated incident that I've only seen on one Mac and would like to figure out why this happens. Trying to research this issue, I came across threads that mention a [ghosted keychain](https://github.com/rsms/fb-mac-messenger/issues/324#issuecomment-274601055) but I've confirmed that it's not the case this time.